# Como manter uma sincronização em tempo real?

Tags: banco-de-dados, ios, objective-c, sincronização

Estou elaborando um app e já tenho o tratamento do banco de dados finalizado.
Mas surgiu uma dúvida de como posso criar um sistema de sincronização em tempo real do banco local do app com o banco do servidor remoto.

Se alguém souber explicar ou tiver um tutorial relacionado fico grato.

Comment: [Aqui](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html) fala algo sobre esse processo.

Comment: Obrigado @"Mechanic, pelo que vi é um serviço de backend que oferece a ferramenta de sincronização em tempo real, mas o codido de exemplo deles e a explicação é boa. Obrigado.

Comment: Vamos imaginar que vc tem um tablet com um BDD e um servidor com um BDD. Se vc quer sincronizar os 2, por exemplo cada 2 horas, tudo bem, isso parece lógico. Mas se vc quer sincronizar 'em tempo real', porque ter um BDD "local"??? Precisa somente enviar or dados da tablet pelo servidor e salvar os dados na BDD do servidor. Como no web: um servidor com a BDD e varias clientes que não tem BDD mas que enviam os dados no servidor. Não?

Comment: Sim eu entendi a logica que vc propôs. Mas como oq falo é de uma estrutura onde o banco comunica e envia ao app cliente que existem novos dados e o envia de forma automatizada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de algumas pesquisas na internet, e graças ao amigo @QMechanic73, verifiquei que esta é uma ferramenta bastante usada em banco de dados NOSQL. 
 Que são sistemas de armazenamentos que não usam SQL(ou sistemas de relacionamento por tabelas).

O link apresentado por @Mechanic73 leva ao site do CoachDB onde possui um tutorial explicando sobre o serviço de sincronização e com um exemplo de uso.

Link [CoachDB](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/couchbase-lite/native-api/replication/index.html).

Obrigado.